# how to place div in front of a table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

i am having trouble in placing my div in front of my table

here is my css for the div I want to pop up

```
#sc_div_option{
                width:300px;
                height:300px;
                border:solid gray 1px;
                display:none;
                position: fixed;
                float:right;
                background-color:green;
                z-index:99999999999999999999999999;
            }
```

and here is my table style

```
 #excel_table{
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    min-height: 30%;
    z-index: -1;

 }
```

I already added z-index and position but does not work

appreciate your help

maybe you are wondering why I am doing this..
i want to have a menu list when I click one of my table data and pop up the div in front here is my jquery responsible for that

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX; 
   mouseY = e.pageY;
});  
$(document).on("click",".scname_value",function(){
     $('#sc_div_option').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
})
```

Tingug sad tawn mo please bitaw ni...

here is my image to show the problem

[image]

Comment: what you mean by "above" div on top of table ?, your question heading and description seems to be vague

Comment: I mean in front of the table

Comment: like a popup dialog ?

Comment: You need boot strap modal.

Comment: yes but it will appear in the position of my mouse cursor and I already achieve that one, my problem is it is behind my table not in front

Comment: see my image added, green is my pop-up but it is behind my table :(

Comment: Is it possible to make a demo (jsfiddle) for better understanding.

Comment: You can use the z-index css property to manage the visible position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just basically set your z-indexes for your content div set z-index: 1 and for the div to pop up to z-index: 2

Comment: WOW! it works,  I just add z-index: 1; to my wrapper and z-index:2; to my pop up div , and it works now I can see it in front Brilliant!! da jud.....

Answer (score 1):

from my understanding , you want to show the popup on top of your table.
for that you have to play with css position.
I have fiddled the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L2d4e415/). you can refer that.parent div of your popup should be of position relative and position of popup should be absolute. and you can set the position from jquery as well as you did for now.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="my-table">
        <tr>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
            <td>hjskladj</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <div class="my-popup">this is my div</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
.my-table td {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}
.my-popup {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

just try this and let me know if it works

Comment: hi still my pop up in the back :(

Answer (score 1):

The CSS z-index property only works on positioned elements. The only issue you seem to have is that `#excel_table` doesn't have a position attribute. Just set it to relative or absolute (in your case, relative seems to be what you want).

Example of z-index with and without position attributes: https://jsfiddle.net/7zxgrb3k/1

```js
var dir = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for(var i=0; i<dir.length; ++i) {
    dir[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(dir[i].className));
}
```

```css
.absolute { position: absolute; }
.relative { position: relative; }
.front { z-index: 10; }
.back { z-index: 0; }

div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -20px;
    
    background-color: #333;
    border: solid 4px #eee;
    border-left: solid 4px #e00;
    border-right: solid 4px #00e;
    color: #eee;
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="front"></div>
<div class="back"></div>
<div class="front"></div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="front relative"></div>
<div class="back relative"></div>
<div class="front relative"></div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="front absolute"></div>
<div class="back absolute"></div>
<div class="front absolute"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Javascript code: here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6aKT/131/)

```
<script>
function showCoords(event) {
var x = event.clientX;
var y = event.clientY;
var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
console.log(var);
var sc_div_option =  document.getElementById("sc_div_option");
sc_div_option.style.display = "block";
sc_div_option.style.top = y+"px";
sc_div_option.style.left = x+"px";
sc_div_option.innerHTML = coords;
```

}

Or use bootstrap modal. [Here is JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6aKT/129/)
You have to use bootstrap modal. You have to  put tha div id as    data-target attribute value . Assign the bellowed think as  your div  css attributes. And in the div add other divs   content, header, footer. Enjoy!

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" > 
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" > </script>
    <table border="1">
    <tr><td col>
     <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sc_div_option">Click Here11</p> 
    </td> <td>
     <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sc_div_option">Click Here12</p> 
    </td><td>
     <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sc_div_option">Click Here13</p> 
    </td><tr>
    <tr><td>
     <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sc_div_option">Click Here21</p> 
    </td><td>
     <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sc_div_option">Click Here22</p> 
    </td><td>
     <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sc_div_option">Click Here23</p> 
    </td><tr>
</table>


   <div class="modal fade" id="sc_div_option" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="id" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
          Header
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"> 
             Body
            <div class="modal-footer">
             Footer
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think OP need to use bootstrap for this, he just wants to show a menu.

Comment: But if he put that menu in the body of the div then he can he. he can also remove the header and footer.

Comment: I didn't said it wont work, defntly it'll work. but for one simple popup he doesn't need to use bootstrap.

Comment: hi, it is working but I need an effect that is not a pop up , I want to show the div in the cursor position just what my jquery is doing , its like you right click the page and it shows you some menu..  thanks any way